# HostNameCanonicalizationWorker:Failed to obtain name info: fe80::** :****:****:****,"errno:11004 requested name valid but not found

Tags: mongodb, database-administration

I am very new to using MongoDB. I have tried installing the 
mongodb-win32-x86_64-2008plus-ssl-3.2.6-signed.msi on a production server.

I have opened command prompt using
C:\mongodb\bin> mongod.exe --port **** 
The port number is different from the default port 27017.

My application is working as expected inserting data and retrieving is also fine.

But, the mongod.exe on that port **** gives me the following repeatedly

W NETWORK [ HostName CanonicalizationWorker] Failed to obtain name info for: [( fe80::** :****:****:****, "errno:11004  The requested name is valid, but no data of the requested type was found.")]

Is this related to MongoDB? How can I solve this issue. I did not find any information regarding this specific error message. 
Kindly help!

Thank you.